Operating with private objects in other classess
I am working with these 2 classes:
public class Journey
{
    private int journeyID;                 // the id of the journey
    private String transportMode;          // the public transport mode of the journey (can be only “train”, “bus” or “tram”) 
    private int startOfJourney;            // the starting point of the journey. It can be only a number between [1..10] 
    private int endOfJourney;              // the ending point of the journey. It can be only a number between [1..10] (should be different from the starting point of the journey)
    private int distanceOfJourney; 

public class SmartCard
{
    private int cardID;           // the id of the smartcard
    private char type;            // the type of the smartcard (it can be "C", "A" or "S")
    private float balance;       // the balance available on the smartcard (should have a minimum balance of $5)
    private Journey journey1 = null;             // journey object
    private Journey journey2 = null;             // journey object - can only be used if the type of the smartcard is "A" or "S"
    private Journey journey3 = null;

and I need to write a method for adding new Journeys to one of the existing SmartCards. However, I can not figure out how to access journey1 objects without changing it to public. I am not allowed to use ArrayList in this task so can I have any suggestions on how to operate with objects in classes? Thank you.
I try to access the Journey object with
smartCard1.journey1 == null;

but it declared that I cannot access a private object. Instead I try creating a getJourneyID() method and use
smartCard1.journey1.getJourneyID()==0;

but it would not work either.

Why would you use 3 separate Journey variables? Is it not better to use a container like ArrayList, an array or your own implementation of linked list to store Journeys? It would also make it easier to make a setter to add Journey to a private variable. Else you would have 3 separate methods like public void setJourney1(Journey j){} public void setJourney2(Journey j){} public void setJourney3(Journey j){}. Anyway, the answer you are looking for lies in setter methods.

The journey class has getters? Why not the smartcard class?

See if this helps: Java :Setter Getter and constructor

3 seperate Journey variables are mandatory and I am not allowed to use ArrayList as we have not covered this in the lectures. That makes the assignment so much more confusing @BIBOOunit

even if arraylist is not allowed, i mentioned an alternative such as an array

I created setters and getters for both journey and smartcard class but I was not sure how to create a getter for private Journey objects in SmartCard class. @OneCricketeer

You could make both smartCard1.getJourney1() .getJourneyID() or smartCard1.getJourney1ID()

See Mutator Method at Wikipedia. Also known as getter/setter methods.
You can keep the member field private yet provide read and/or write access via get…/set… methods.
public class SmartCard
{
    private int cardID;        
    private Journey journey = null; 
    …
    public void setJourney ( final Journey journey ) 
    {
        Objects.requireNonNull( journey ) ;
        this.journey = journey ; 
    }
}

You said:

can only be used if the type of the smartcard is "A" or "S"

That kind of logic can be added to the setter method.
